# Как получить JSONobject используя Retrofit?

Tags: android, json, retrofit

```
    public interface ApiRequests {
     @POST("user/check")
        Call<JSONObject> login(@QueryMap Map<String, String> options);
    }

  Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(API_SERVER_URL)
                .build();

        ApiRequests api = retrofit.create(ApiRequests.class);
        Call call = api.login(params);

call.enqueue(new Callback<JSONObject>() {
                         @Override
                         public void onResponse(Call<JSONObject> call, Response<JSONObject> response) {
....
```

Ошибка: Unable to create converter for class org.json.JSONObject
но мне же конвертер не нужен.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте такой тип возвращаемого объекта: `Response<ResponseBody>` - из него вы сможете вот так получить ответ сервера в виде строки:

```
String body = response.body().string();
```

Далее вам останется только взять любой парсер JSON-а и получить то, что вам нужно

Comment: Не, возвращает: okhttp3.ResponseBody$1@3cafc0b9

Comment: @Igor, обновит вопрос, приведите ваш текущий код. То, что вы написали - это результат вызова `toString` метода объекта. Возможно вам надо таки `string()` как в ответе вызвать вместо негою.